# Start LXDE with Lubuntu configuration using command

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, nx

On my computer I have a neat little Lubuntu installation running. It loads a nice LXDE desktop themed with the nice Lubuntu theme whenever I use `lxdm` to login. When I use the `startlxde` command to start LXDE however, the desktop session that gets loaded is a default, bare bones LXDE session which appeals less to my taste. Kind of a shame!

The reason that I use startlxde to start a session is that I'm attempting to log on remotely using NX. I need to supply a command to NX that starts up an X desktop it can use, and `startlxde` does just that. But as stated above doesn't load the right theming and lxpanel configurations unfortunately.

Is there a way to load the same Lubuntu configuration (with the proper theming and `lxpanel` settings) as `lxdm` does when I log on over NX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I connect to Lubuntu using NoMachine's client under Windows  7.  Under your NX client connection under the Desktop area, select "Custom", then click on settings. Just be sure the settings look like this:

[image: NXClient Settings for Lubuntu]

Now connect and you're ready to go.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Kind of feel stupid for overlooking it!

Comment: I did not have the `startlubuntu` command.  I had to use `lxsession -s LXDE` instead.  Also, it is important to have the `New virtual desktop` box checked.