# Can't use startx with lxde?

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, gui, lxde

I use Lubuntu 13.10 and start default with "text".

When i need to use GUI, `startx` didn't work, but "`service lightdm start`" is worked.

How to use `startx` with LXDE?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Console

To use `startx`, you will need to define LXDE in your ~/.xinitrc file:

```
exec startlxde
```

If you want to run `startx` at boot automatically, take a look at the [Starting X at boot guide.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Boot#Starting_X_as_preferred_user_without_logging_in)

Comment: Thank you so much! It's worked!

But when startlxde, it's i think a simple one of the default lubuntu's interface. If i want to use default Lubuntu's interface which command should i use? 

'"startlightdm?'

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I don't use LUbuntu but my guess is that you are not into a "simple" version of LUbuntu, but in the normal one. Why do you assume you are into a simpler interface?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96861/start-lxde-with-lubuntu-configuration-using-command

I think this is my problem, but i can't use command "startlubuntu" in xinitrc file :D